# Does Powershell string interpolation support format specifiers

Tags: c#, powershell, string-interpolation

Typical string formatting in powershell for instance to use padding or specifying number can be written like this:

```
>>> "x={0,5} and y={1:F3}" -f $x, $y
x=   10 and y=0.333
```

But in Powershell you can also use string interpolation like

```
>>> $x=10
>>> $y=1/3
>>> "x=$x and y=$y"
x=10 and y=0.333333333333333
```

And in C# string interpolation also supports the formatting specifiers:

```
> var x = 10;
> var y = 1.0/3.0;
> $"x={x,5} and y = {y:F2}";
"x=   10 and y = 0.33"
```

Is there a way to have that in Powershell? I've tried many combinations like

```
>>> "var=$($var, 10)"
var=10 10
```

but none of them work. Is this supported? Or is there a succinct way to call into C# to use it?

*update* as Mathias answers and as confirmed on Powershell's github this is currently not supported, so I made a [feature request here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12259)

Comment: I assume you mean `"var={0,10}" -f $var` like in my second code example. Well, because I like inline string interpolation, am used to the syntax from other languages, it's somewhat shorter and I find it more readable (usually).

Comment: Not clear what you are asking here.. Do you mean to left-pad the variable `$var`? In that case, you could use the String method `PadLeft`, something like `"var=$($var.ToString().PadLeft(5))"`

Comment: @Theo yes, padding, formatting numbers and dates etc, the usual C# things. See edit for clarification. Something like what you propse works of course, but it's not very succinct.

Comment: @stijn - from what i can tell ... NO. the only way to use string composition is to use the `-f` string format operator. there is [apparently] no other way in powershell to do that stuff.

Comment: `"$(' '*10)$var"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this supported?

## No, formatting is not supported during string expansion

---

As you might have noticed, string expansion in PowerShell works by naively resolving subexpressions nested in double-quoted strings - there are no `{}` placeholder constructs.

If you want string *formatting*, `-f` is the way to go.

FWIW, `$s -f $a` is directly translated to a `String.Format($s, $a)` call

For value types that support string formatting you can usually also call `ToString()` with a format string (just like in C#):

```
PS C:\> $a = 1 / 3 
PS C:\> $a.ToString("F2")
0.33
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to go with this is to use the `-f` operator. The `-f` operator takes a format string as it's first operand and the items you want to format as the second. The format string must contain tokens like `{n:f}` where `n` is the index of the item in the items to be formatted and `f` is the format specifier. For example `{0:D4}` will take the first item and format it as a Decimal that is a minimum of 4 digits. So `'{0:D4}-{1:D3}' -f 24,3` gives the output `0024-003`. ref

Inside an expandable string this can be used within a subexpression operator `$()`.

A real world example is to split an input file into multiple files with ten lines in each while making the the output file name contain a serial number wich is padded with zeros to make it four digits. This can be done like this:

```
$i = 0; Get-Content input.txt -ReadCount 10 | %{ $i++; $_ | Out-File "output_$('{0:D4}' -f $i).txt" }
```

Creates files

```
output_0001.txt
output_0002.txt
...
```